# yii2 как создать группы пользователей?

Tags: php, yii2, users, manager

Ситуация такая, нужно сделать так!

1. Есть менеджер_1 у него свои пользователи и он видит только их посты!
2. Есть менеджер_2 у него свои пользователи и он видит только их посты!
3. Есть менеджер_3 у него свои пользователи и он видит только их посты!

И т.д.
Я так предполагаю это группы пользователей! может и ошибаюсь.
Подскажите куда копать читаю про rbac, не могу понять как сделать эту структуру через него. Спасибо.

Comment: Что подразумевается под словом "видит"? Если только видеть, то обыкновенный запрос с INNER JOIN

Comment: Если нужны группы пользователей, читайте документацию по YII2 RBAC и делайте по аналогии

Answer (score 2):

RBAC позволяет настроить роли и разрешения. Разрешения даются на определенные разделы сайта, например, site/user, site/post и т. д. Разрешения группируются в роли для удобства.
Поэтому RBAC, насколько я понял, для Вашей цели не очень подходит.
Вам, видимо, потребуется создать свою систему прав. К статье добавить признак автора, например, столбец с ID. А дальше выбирать статьи, в зависимости от того, какой менеджер просматривает список статей. Также должна быть таблица пользователей, групп пользователей и переходная таблица для связи многие-ко-многим (групп и пользователей)